# Result of subtraction either positive or zero

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to perform a subtraction where the result must be either positive or zero. I will use some pseudo code to represent what I mean (like it is not clear enough but still).

```
function subtract(x, y) {
    result = x - y

    if (result < 0) {
        result = 0
    }

    return result
}
```

Now as a programmer I know my ways around math, but I am far from a mathematician. I would like to ask if there is any math wizardry that would do this for me instead of having to check the result before returning it, something like an absolute value - if there was no absolute value function I would have to check if the number is less than 0 and if yes multiply by -1. I hope I'm making sense.

P.S.: I'm completely unaware of what tags to use for this, please excuse me and edit if possible.

Comment: No, you aren't really making sense. The code snippet specifies that for $x<0$ you return $0$, while the text seems to require $-x$. "Something like an absolute value" is ambiguous.

Comment: Your pseudocode makes sense (to me) though your text does not. I think any "math wizardry" that replaces the pseudocode would just be doing essentially the same test under the covers.

Comment: Would be helpful to tell us why you are asking this question.

Comment: Either you want a efficient code or a readable code, or both. I don't think using any other magical function will speed this simple code, as far readability goes you always have ternary operator. P.S this looks like javascript, i don't know if it support ternary, i am not a programmer.

Comment: Asking for 'Math wizardry' questions as a programmer is kind of silly. Not only will the people who might look through your code (with a similar skill set) to yours not understand it as easily as your 'pseudo-code' … But it's a terrible idea performance-wise as well. Even though the accepted answer is technically correct, it is much slower, you might feel like calling a library function for the absolute value (I hope not), the compiler might not optimise it, the processor might not correctly predict the flow, et cetera.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try
$$
\text{result} = (|x-y|+x-y)/2
$$
If $x\geqslant y$, then $\text{result} =x-y$ and if $x<y$, then $\text{result} =0$

Comment: i think this is the closest to be "mathematical wizardry"

Comment: This expression should be equivalent to Doug Chatham's, since the maximum of two functions is given by $(|f-g|+(f+g))/2$, here with $f(x) = x- y$ and $g(x) = 0$

Comment: So many operations! I count 5 operations for something that's unreadable. If this were code review stack exchange, I would suggest that @php_nub_qq did not use this method and used one of the others suggested or even the one originally provided in the question.

Answer (score 23):

I suggest $\max\{0, x-y\}$, the maximum of zero and $(x-y).$

Answer (score 15):

You are writing a program — you don't want *math* wizardry, you want *programming* wizardry.

*Math* wizardry will tend to aim for expressing things in terms that are convenient to work with for various *mathematical* purposes.

But what you need is something that:

- Makes for an efficient program
- Is easy for programmers to read

and the thing is, what you've written is already pretty much *optimal* for that purpose.

(I assume now you are writing in something like C or C++)

In fact, I would actually expect the entire `if` statement to be translated to a *single machine language instruction*: there are two likely possibilities depending on the architecture:

- a conditional move depending on the sign of the previous arithmetic instruction
- a `max` instruction, if your architecture has one

You basically can't do better than that unless your architecture offers a single instruction whose job is to do exactly what your function does — and even then it's the job of the *compiler* to recognize that and choose that instruction, rather than you writing an arcane program.

Comment: In terms of readability, I would prefer `return x > y ? x - y : 0;`

Comment: @YvesDaoust Put that in a macro and it's a deal, no need to make functions :-p.

Comment: @YoTengo: Except, of course, that functions are better in every way. But that's a topic for one of the computer stackexchanges.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: my comment is about readability. Using a macro will have no positive impact, `#define PosDif(x, y) ((x) > (y) ? (x) - (y) : 0)` isn't more readable in any way.

Answer (score 1):

What if your function was something like this?

```
function subtract( x, y ) {
    if( x < y ) // difference will be negative
        return 0;
    else
        return x - y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One can completely avoid the unpleasant cache effects of a branch by using the pre-calculated sign bit.

**Update** - corrected hurried misreading of spec.

```
/// <summary>Return difference of operands, or zero if negative.</summary>
function subtract(x, y) {
    result = x - y

    return result * (1 + Math.Sign(result) ) / 2;
}
```

This code is simply arithmetic operations, all of which are highly optimized on modern CPU's.

Comment: This will return $y - x$ when $x < y$. I thought we were supposed to return $0$ in that case.

Comment: @DavidK: Oops! I have corrected now to match spec.

Comment: A bunch of years later, this is interesting, but isn't a function call - which probably has branching - much more expensive than a single branch?

Comment: @php_nub_qq: Why on Earth would a call into Math.Sign() have any branches? That would be horrendously inefficient as well as totally unnecessary. When you're using a math library, or any system library for that matter, just choose one that's sanely implemented.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens fair point, still the function call *should* be more expensive than a branch? Perhaps a solution including reading the first bit would be the best choice but that would be platform dependent, I suppose.

Comment: @php_nub_qq: Stop doing the compiler's job. Short functions routinely get in-lined instead of called. Subsequently, if such a call is deeply nested, inefficient, and not in-lined, that will stick out like a sore thumb in a performance analysis so that it can be in-lined manually. Until then: don't muck with premature optimization at the cost of code clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like Javascript, in which case you **should have written**:

```
function subtract(x,y) { return ( x<y ? 0 : x-y ); }
```

This is **both the clearest and the fastest**.

Comment: The reason it is even clearer than using `Math.max(x-y,0)` is that it never performs the subtraction unless the result will be non-negative, which is probably **exactly** the intended meaning.